# Java Multithreading synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading

I am having a trouble to share a resource with three threads...

```
 public class Subject{

        int i;
        boolean valueSet1 = false;
        boolean valueSet2 = true;
        boolean valueSet3 = true;

    void put(int i){

        while(valueSet1){
            try{
                wait();
               }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    System.out.println("Producer thread interrupted");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Producer thread wakesup");
            valueSet1=true;
            valueSet2=false;
            this.i=i;        
            System.out.println("Put: "+i);
            notify();
        }


    void makesquare(){

            int a;   
            while(valueSet2){
                try{
                    System.out.println("Convertor thread goin to sleep");
                    wait();
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    System.out.println("Convertor thread interrupted");
                }
            }       
            System.out.println("Convertor thread wakesup");
            valueSet2 = true;
            valueSet3=false;
            a = this.i;
            this.i = a*a;
            System.out.println("Made: "+i);        
            notify();
    }

    void get(){

           while(valueSet3){
                try{
                    System.out.println("Consumer thread goin to sleep");                
                    wait();
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    System.out.println("Consumer thread interrupted");
                }
            }
           System.out.println("Consumer thread wakesup");
           valueSet3 = true;
           valueSet1 = false;
           System.out.println("Got: "+i);
           notify();       
    }

    }

    class Producer implements Runnable{

        Subject q;    
        Thread t;
        String msg; 
        Producer(Subject q, String msg){
            this.q=q;
            this.msg = msg;
            t = new Thread(this, this.msg);
        }
        @Override
        public void run(){
            int i=2;
            while(true){
                synchronized(q){
                q.put(i++);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    class Consumer implements Runnable{

        Subject q;    
        Thread t;
        String msg;
        Consumer(Subject q,String msg){
            this.q = q;
            this.msg = msg;
            t = new Thread(this, this.msg);
        }
        @Override
        public void run(){
            while(true){
                synchronized(q){
                q.get();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Convertor implements Runnable{
        Subject q;   
        Thread t;
        String msg;
        Convertor(Subject q, String msg){
            this.q=q;
            this.msg = msg;
            t = new Thread(this, this.msg);    
        }
        @Override
        public void run(){
            while(true){
                synchronized(q){
                q.makesquare();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

There are three threads in the program. One thread produces while another makes square of the produced quantity. While the last thread consumes the squared product.They all share the same object.

```
    public class Thread3way {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
           Subject q = new Subject();
           Producer P = new Producer(q, "producer");
           Convertor Cv = new Convertor(q, "convertor");
           Consumer Cs = new Consumer(q, "consumer");
           P.t.start();
           Cv.t.start();
           Cs.t.start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please edit your post to show more information about what is going on.  What output or behavior are you seeing or missing? If there is an exception be sure to add it.

Comment: Why don't you use notifyAll() instead of notify() (as you are synchronizing 3 threads)

Comment: Also, if you are synchronize on the Subject object (which you are doing) you don't need to mark all the methods as synchronized.

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez Thankyou very much..it worked.. but why wasn't it working with notify?

Comment: @Dave I mentioned my problem on top of the code.

Comment: @Tej: "I'm having a trouble" is way too vague of a problem.  What kind of trouble?  What is happening when you run your code?  How does its behavior not match your goal?

Comment: @KeithRandall When I executed the code all the three threads go to sleep after executing                                               "Put: 2
Made: 4
Got: 4"

Comment: @Tej: then it is almost certainly your use of `notify` instead of `notifyAll`, as Alexandre mentions.

Comment: @Tej When you call notify(), only one thread is notified that a lock has been released by the thread which calls notify(). notifyAll() allows to notify all the tread waiting for a lock to be released. If more than one thread are waiting for a lock owned by another thread, as in your program, you must call notifyAll() so that all the blocked threads get a chance to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Your `wait` loop is not quite correct, you need to keep looping until your condition is true *before* you do any modifications.  I'd do it like this (using a `State` enum to make things clearer):

```
public class Subject {
    static enum State { EMPTY, WAITING_TO_SQUARE, WAITING_TO_GET };
    State state;
    int value;

    public synchronized void put(int i) {
        while (state != State.EMPTY) {
            try {
                wait();
            }catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Put interrupted");
            }
        }
        value = i;
        state = State.WAITING_TO_SQUARE;
    }
}
```

As a commenter pointed out, you don't need to synchronize twice, either `synchronized(q)` around the `Subject` calls, *or* declare your methods `synchronized`.  You don't need both.

No need to use `Runnables` explicitly, just make `Producer`, `Convertor`, and `Consumer` `Thread`s directly.  Then you don't need the `t` fields, and you can start the threads like `P.start()`.

Comment: Thank yo very much..                                                 But I did not understand the statement "No need to ...P.start()"..How can you implement without runnables?

Comment: @Tej: you can subclass `Producer` from `Thread`, then do `Producer p = new Producer(...); p.start();`.  `Thread` implements `Runnable` so your `run` method will get called when `p` starts.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you're doing some kind of pipeline with 3 stages. Why not enjoy the benefits of `ExecutorService`:

```
class ConvertorTask implements Runnable {

    private int number;
    private static ExecutorService consumer = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public ConvertorTask(int number) {
        this.number = number;       
    }

    public void run() {
        consumer.submit(new ConsumerTask(number * number));
    }
}

class ConsumerTask implements Runnable {

    private int number;

    public ConsumerTask(int number) {
        this.number = number;       
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}

class Producer implements Runnable {

    private ExecutorService convertor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        while(true) {           
            convertor.submit(new ConvertorTask(i++));
        }
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {        
        Thread t = new Thread(new Producer());
        t.start();
    }
}
```